# jquery hoverintent - mouseenter on one element, mouseleave on another

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hoverintent

I'm trying to use the [hoverintent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to replace the following javascript code:

```
$('#top').on('mouseenter', '#nav', function(e){
    $('#top ul').delay(100).slideDown(300);
    $('#top').stop().animate({
        height: 230
    }, 400);
});

$('body').on('mouseleave', '#top', function(e){
    $('#top ul').slideUp(300);
    $('#top').stop().animate({
        height: 97
    }, 400);
});
```

My html is:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="top">
        <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
        <ol id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Company</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
html { background:#fff; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

#main { position: relative; width: 860px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left; padding: 0 40px; }

#top { width: 860px; height: 97px; border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f1f0; padding-bottom: 30px; }
#top a.logo { display: block; float: left; width: 186px; height: 55px; margin-top: 40px; background: #ccc; }
#top a.logo:hover { background: #ddd; }

#top ol { position: absolute; top: 37px; right: 40px; display: block; overflow: visible; z-index: 10; }
#top ol li { display: inline-block; float: left; text-align: right; margin-left: 24px; padding-top: 20px; }
#top ol li a { display: block; font-family: "Arial Narrow", "Helvetica Narrow", sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em; color: #989f98; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px; }
#top ol li a.current,
#top ol li a:hover { color: #e9292f; }

#top ul { display: none; padding-bottom: 6px; max-width: 95px; border-top: 1px dotted #d1d1d1; }
#top ul li { display: block; float: none; margin-left: 0; padding-top: 3px; }
#top ul li a { font-size: 0.7em; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-transform: none; }
```

Here is a quick diagram on what I am trying to achieve:

[image: diagram]

All I want is for the user to mouseover the `#nav` and only have it disappear when they take their mouse out of the `#top` (grey in my diagram). Given the examples on the hoverintent site, I am not sure how to achieve this :(

Anyone got any pointers? Thanks in advance!

**------ EDIT ------**

Have got hoverintent working up to a point by doing:

```
var config = {    
    over: function(){
        $('#top ul').delay(100).slideDown(300);
        $('#top').stop().animate({
            height: 230
        }, 400);
    },
    timeout: 0,    
    out: function(){
        $('#top ul').slideUp(300);
        $('#top').stop().animate({
            height: 97
        }, 400);
    }
};

$('#nav').hoverIntent(config);
```

The problem is now my `ul` disappear when I mouse out of `#nav` instead of my `#top` div. Close but no cigar :(

Answer (score 0):

This may not suit your situation, but if you wanted a non javascript method:

http://www.ryancollins.me/?p=1041

This works well. Also the principals at play here are also relevant to any javascript method as well.

Basically, you need a few variables.

navHover = false;
subNavHover = false;

When mousing in and out of the obvious elements simply set their variables to true/false.

Next, on mouse leave for both, do a quick check:

```
if( navHover )
```

or

```
if( subNavHover )
```

If either variable is set to true, don't hide the nav. If you want animations, you'll need to use callbacks and perhaps a quick timeout delay so that it doesn't hide too soon.

But I'd go with the CSS only version if I were you!

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Tried doing it this way and it hasn't had the desired effect. My problem is I want the 'over' to happen on one element and the 'out' on another. Hoverintent is set up to have both happen on the same element :(

Answer (score 0):

as you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj8sj/ your jQuery code works.

I think its a css problem you have... I assume you have positioned your #nav with a float. What coses #top to have only the height of its non floating content. You could fix this by using: `#top { overflow: hidden; }` Same thing for the UL's and the in the #nav element.

please provide some CSS to if this does not fix your problem

Update: Now that you have posted the CSS... Same effect for position absolute elements, they don't adapt the height of the parent.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post my css - I have added it to my original post. I don't think this is a css issue though...

Comment: @boz: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj8sj/6/ as you can see the red zone does not get any higher when you hover the subnav. But it works fine...

Comment: Whoops - this is what happens when I try and extract code from a larger codebase. I missed out the fact I'm animating the height of <code>#top</code> too. Sorry about that :(